# jQuery .load() stops complete script on iPhone/Android without error message

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

Since I add the following lines to mij jQuery script, the whole jQuery is not working anymore on Mobile Devices. On all the PC browsers everything works fine

```
if ( $("input[name=campaign_id").val() ) {  
  $('#address').load('/Xscripts/fetch_users_data.php?cid=' + $("input[name=campaign_id").val(), function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
  if(statusTxt == "error")
    alert("Error by loading data: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
  });
};
```

There is no error message, but just all the jQuery functions are completely not working.

Does anyone have any clue how to fix this? How can this load code make the complete jQuery-script crashing on iPhone and Android? Removing these lines makes the rest of the script running again.

Many thanks in advance,

NiFa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK lets try some things

1st close input attr with ] .. replace a next code in both places

```
$("input[name=campaign_id]").val()
                   ------^------
```

2nd for load url you can try

```
'Xscripts/fetch_users_data.php?cid=' + $("input[name=campaign_id]").val()
```

or

```
'./Xscripts/fetch_users_data.php?cid=' + $("input[name=campaign_id]").val()
```

hope it helps